# Make services available only locally

Tags: networking

When I `nmap` my raspi (`nmap -6 -p- domain.sth`) which is connected to the internet and runs Ubuntu Mate 16.04, I get this result:

```
Not shown: 65532 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
5900/tcp open  vnc
```

I want ssh to be accessible from all over the internet but don't want smtp nor vnc to be accessible except locally. I.e. I can't just stop smtp and vnc because I still want mails to be sent locally and I still want to ssh into my raspi and then use vnc. I tell my vnc client to connect to `localhost` but to tunnel to my raspi via ssh first.

The services shouldn't be accessible within the same network either. It would be nice if this worked both for IPv4 and IPv6. The device can't be reached via IPv4 from the internet anyways (only via IPv6) but within the same network, reaching it via IPv4 is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- Configure both services to bind to localhost (127.0.0.1 and ::1) instead of the wildcard address (0.0.0.0 and ::). This is considered "cleaner" (and definitely more portable).
- Use `iptables` to drop incoming connections to them.

Of course, you can do both, for defense in depth.

Comment: Do you have a link to something explaining how to do the first option?

Comment: Depends on how the configuration of your SMTP server and VNC server works.